# Keeping indent on list when viewport constrained

Tags: css

I am styling a list outputted by a CMS.  I can only insert classes on the outer div.  Structure of HTML if fixed.

I used before/after trick in order to give a font-awesome icon as a bullet point but when the viewport is constrained and the point overflows to the second line it can look bad, especially when just one or two words overflow.

Is there any way I can maintain the indent for the overflow text?

Here is my markup:

```css
.green-tick-list li:before {    
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
content:"\f00c";
margin:0 5px 0 -15px;
color: #33cc33;
}
.green-tick-list li{
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}

#responsive{
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="fl-module fl-module-rich-text fl-animation fl-slide-right green-tick-list fl-node-56ec97eb4d7e1 fl-animated" data-node="56ec97eb4d7e1" data-animation-delay="0.5">
  <div class="fl-module-content fl-node-content">
    <div class="fl-rich-text">
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply.</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing.</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum.</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<h3>Simulating restricted viewport</h3>
<div id="responsive">
  <div class="fl-module fl-module-rich-text fl-animation fl-slide-right green-tick-list fl-node-56ec97eb4d7e1 fl-animated" data-node="56ec97eb4d7e1" data-animation-delay="0.5">
  <div class="fl-module-content fl-node-content">
    <div class="fl-rich-text">
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply.</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing.</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum.</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I'd like the indent of the overflow text to be in line with the start start of the text. Is that possible?

Comment: set your line height on the font-awesome icon to be the line-height of the element? Should force the overflow text to be pushed to the right.

Comment: did you try adjusting margin property?
.green-tick-list li:before{ margin: 0 5px 0 -20px;}

Comment: `Margin-left` on the `li` should also work

Comment: @VikingBlooded @SamWillis Neither of those solutions work.  Setting margin of the `li` also moves the icon.  Setting the line height of the icon has no effect.